# Compile R Package on Windows from Loose R files

Tags: r

I can find plenty of discussion about how to compile packages from .tar.gz files on Windows but I cannot find anything about compiling packages from loose R files.

Say I have a package on disk like:

- rootdir\inst\somedir\file1.R
- rootdir\inst\somedir\file2.R
- rootdir\R
- rootdir\DESCRIPTION
- rootdir\NAMESPACE

How can I compile this using the CMD INSTALL commands on Windows to produce a package containing the .rdb / .rdx files?

Comment: You could try with `R CMD build <rootdir>` and then install the resulting tar.gz file.

Comment: Start by reading the manual: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of guides on how to make R packages, for starters:

```
library("devtools")
build("rooter")
```

http://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/

Also, a more advanced guide (a book really) is available here:

http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz